# Use two DISTINCT statements in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, distinct-values

I have combined two different tables together, one side is named DynDom and the other is CATH. I am trying to remove duplicates from that table such as below:
[image]

However, if i select distinct Dyndom pdbcode from the table, it returns distinct values of that pdbcode.
[image: DynDom table]
and

[image: CATH]

Based on the pictures above, I commented out the DynDom/CATH columns in the table and ran the query separately for DynDom/CATH and it returned those values accordingly, which is what i need and i was wondering if it's possible for me to use 2 distinct statements to return distinct values of the entire table based on the pdbcode.

Here's my code :

```
select DISTINCT
    cath_dyndom_table_2."DYNDOM_DOMAINID",
    cath_dyndom_table_2."DYNDOM_DSTART",
    cath_dyndom_table_2."DYNDOM_DEND",
    cath_dyndom_table_2."DYNDOM_CONFORMERID",
    cath_dyndom_table_2.pdbcode,
    cath_dyndom_table_2."DYNDOM_ChainID",
    cath_dyndom_table_2.cath_pdbcode,
    cath_dyndom_table_2."CATH_BEGIN",
    cath_dyndom_table_2."CATH_END"
from 
    cath_dyndom_table_2 
where 
    pdbcode = '2hun'
order by 
    cath_dyndom_table_2."DYNDOM_DOMAINID",
    cath_dyndom_table_2."DYNDOM_DSTART",
    cath_dyndom_table_2."DYNDOM_DEND",
    cath_dyndom_table_2.pdbcode,
    cath_dyndom_table_2.cath_pdbcode,
    cath_dyndom_table_2."CATH_BEGIN",
    cath_dyndom_table_2."CATH_END";
```

In the end, i would like to search domains from DynDom and CATH, based on the pdbcode and return the rows without having duplicate values.

Thank you.

### ***UPDATE :***

This is my VIEW table that i have done.

```
    CREATE VIEW cath_dyndom_table AS
SELECT
  r.domainid AS "DYNDOM_DOMAINID",
  r.DomainStart AS "DYNDOM_DSTART",
  r.Domain_End AS "DYNDOM_DEND",
  r.ddid AS "DYN_DDID",
  r.confid AS "DYNDOM_CONFORMERID",
  r.pdbcode,
  r.chainid AS "DYNDOM_ChainID",
  d.cath_pdbcode,
  d.cathbegin AS "CATH_BEGIN",
  d.cathend AS "CATH_END"
FROM dyndom_domain_table r
  FULL OUTER JOIN cath_domains d ON d.cath_pdbcode::character(4) = r.pdbcode 
  ORDER BY confid ASC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you want a UNION of domain name and ranges from each table - this can be achieved like so:

```
SELECT DYNDOM_DOMAINID, DYNDOM_DSTART, DYNDOM_DEND
FROM DynDom
UNION
SELECT RTRIM(cath_pdbcode), CATH_BEGIN, CATH_END
FROM CATH
```

This should eliminate exact duplicates (ie. where the domain name, start and end are all identical) but will not eliminate duplicate domain names with different ranges - if these exist you will need to decide how to handle them (retain them as separate entries, combine them with lowest start and highest end, or whatever other option is preferred).

EDIT: Actually, I believe you can get the desired results simply by changing the JOIN ON condition in your view to be:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN cath_domains d 
ON d.cath_pdbcode::character(5) = r.pdbcode || r.chainid AND
   r.DomainStart <= d.cathbegin AND
   r.Domain_End >= d.cathend
```

Comment: Well it sort of works, but since its a union, it returns all of the matching pdbcodes in a single column. I don't want that. It's sort of what i explained in my question with the last two pictures, i actually want to join those together without using a union statement. This is where i am stuck at and i dont know what to do. Please advise.

Comment: @jeiman90: Your last two pictures show what you have already achieved, not what you are trying to do. Please can you clarify what you actually want? So far you have only listed what you *don't* want to do.

Comment: My apologies, basically from the first picture that i posted at the top of the question, i would like to remove duplicate values from the `DYNDOM_DSTART and DYNDOM_DEND` and `CATH_BEGIN, CATH_END` columns. I have tried many methods and they don't seem to work efficiently. I have updated my question with my VIEW table that i have created.

Comment: @jeiman90 - I think your view query is pretty close to what you actually need - see my amended answer for a change to the JOIN condition that may meet your requirements.

Comment: It works partially and i see what you have done. You have basically assigned cath_pdbcode to take in 5 characters including the chain id equal to r.pdbcode, but somehow it ignores the other chains by CATH. Any way that i could solve that?

Comment: @jeiman90: I inferred from the data supplied that `cath_domains.cath_pdbcode` was a composite field consisting of the `pdbcode`, followed by the `chainid`, followed by a 2 digit number not held on `dyndom_domain_table`, and that therefore the two tables needed to be joined on the combination of the two fields from `dyndom_domain_table`. I also inferred that the `cathbegin` and `cathend` values of `cath_domains` needed to be entirely within the Domain range values from `dyndom_domain_table`. If either of these inferences are incorrect, the join condition will need to be amended accordingly.

Comment: Ok. I manage to use a normal JOIN condition. But that only returns rows that match with the chainid and pdbcodes. So from 150,000 rows, it has come down to 1500 rows. These 1500 rows are the ones that i partially need, also with the addition of the other pdbcodes that don't match aswell. Thats the reason i did a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 3):

What you are getting is the `cartesian product` of the ´two tables`.

In order to get one line without duplicates you need to have to have a `1-to-1 relation` between both `tables`.

---

You can see [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) what are `cartesian joins` and [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm) how to avoid them!

Comment: how do i do a 1-to-1 relation between the table. And also, the first table at the top is a VIEW table in which i have combined two tables together. Therefore i did two separate DISTINCT statements to select part of the columns.

Comment: @jeiman90 you need to have a column(s) in one table that relate with a column(s) in the other. See the second example that I posted.

Comment: yes i do. The pdbcode. heres the code for my view table that i have created: `SELECT DISTINCT
  r.domainid AS "DYNDOM_DOMAINID",
  r.DomainStart AS "DYNDOM_DSTART",
  r.Domain_End AS "DYNDOM_DEND",
  r.ddid AS "DYN_DDID",
  r.confid AS "DYNDOM_CONFORMERID",
  r.pdbcode,
  r.chainid AS "DYNDOM_ChainID",
  d.cath_pdbcode,
  d.cathbegin AS "CATH_BEGIN",
  d.cathend AS "CATH_END"
FROM dyndom_domain_table r
  FULL OUTER JOIN cath_domains d ON d.cath_pdbcode::character(4) = r.pdbcode 
  ORDER BY r.domainid, r.DomainStart, r.Domain_End, r.pdbcode, d.cath_pdbcode, d.cathbegin, d.cathbegin`

Comment: if you would like, i can update my question with my view table that i have created, since it looks untidy in the comment section.